# Phone application is not hiting webservice in iphone device

Tags: cordova

I have created the phone application, This application works with webservices, its working properly in simulator, but in device it is not working . device cannot able to hit webservice.

i already add the url in config.xml... i am attaching the config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />

<plugins>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
    <plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
    <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser"  />

</plugins>

<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
    <string>192.168.3.253:8086*</string>
</array>


<access origin="*.192.168.3.253:8086.*" subdomain = "true" />
```

"

But it is not working. Please Help Me...

Thanks
keerthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is your external host publicly accessible ?**

If not your application will not be able to access it.

This is a common problem , since any mobile developer be it an android/iphone developer, testing may work on simulator/emulator but wont work when it is deployed on phone.

Comment: Are you sure? 192.168.3.253 look like private local IP to me.

Comment: @wmfairuz, yep, i was not able to access either.

Comment: Hi, I think the URL is not accessible? let me check